# Can I find out gender of my website using analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am using GA tracking code with Doubleclick and can see gender in Google Analytics.
However can I find out gender for particular visit using GA api/GA tags for example to deliver different content?

Thanks

Comment: According to Google "gendre" means either "son" or "son in law" and both seem inapplicable here. Do you mean "gender" ?

Comment: Yes gender. Just if I can access to demographics data via JavaScript on my website from Google analytics. Thank you